# Comparison of the plots of the same line on the Cartesian plane using pgfplots and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the plot of a line using `pgfplots` and the plot of the same line using `TikZ`.  I would like them to be identical.

I need to correct a mistake in the plot of a line using `pgfplots`.  The point that is plotted should be at the point (a, ma+b). Since a=-3 and m=-0.5=b, the point as specified in the code is (-3,-2).  Why is the point not plotted correctly?

In the plot of a line using `TikZ`, I need to put the label "y = mx + b" in the right place.  (Look at the other plot.)  I also need to add two tick marks - one on the x-axis at -3 and one on the y-axis at -2.  I was told that there was a default option for tick marks.  (I was not able to view the `datavisualization library` as described in chapter 75 of the manual at the following web site: texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf .)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-3.5,ymax=2.5,
    restrict y to domain=-3.5:2.5,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-3},
    extra x tick labels={$a$},
    extra y ticks={-2},
    extra y tick labels={$ma+b$},
    yticklabel style={anchor=west},
    yticklabel shift=-4pt,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=201,domain=-5:5,blue] {0.5*x - 0.5} node[above left, pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y = mx + b$};
\draw [fill] (-3,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (0,2.5) +(0,0.5cm) node[above right] {$y$} -- (0,-3.5) -- +(0,-0.5cm);
\draw[draw=gray!30,latex-latex] (-5,0) +(-0.5cm,0) -- (5,0) -- +(0.5cm,0) node[below right] {$x$};
\draw[blue,domain=-5:5,samples=2,latex-latex] plot (\x, 0.5*\x - 0.5) node[above left, pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y = mx + b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\end{document}
```

Comment: When you use normal TikZ commands like `\draw` inside an `axis` environment, you should either use the `axis cs:` coordinate system (so `\draw [fill] (axis cs:-3,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];`), or set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or newer), which activates the `axis cs` coordinate system.

Comment: @Jake I added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` to the preamble. Do you know how to get the same plot using only `TikZ`?

Comment: I think you can't place nodes on a `plot` using the `pos` syntax in plain TikZ, you'll need to either move it manually or draw the plot using a normal path. Just out of curiosity: why do you need to find two ways of achieving the same output?

Comment: @Jake  I have a file with many graphs of lines drawn using `pgfplots.`  One graph that I want has a circle circle that is not centered at the origin.  It really can't be drawn using `pgfplots.`  So, I wanted to replace all the graphs ... but I want them to be consistent with the graphs that I have from `pgfplots`.  I like the way they are drawn with `pgfplots` and I may have to use `pgfplots` in later editions of this file.

Comment: @Jake  Do you know how to put the dot in the right place?

Comment: For putting the dot in the right place, use `\draw [fill] (axis cs:-3,-2) circle [radius=1.5pt];`. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Jake  You answered my question.  Do I really need "axis cs:" if I am using `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`?

Comment: No, you don't. That's what I meant in my first comment, either use `axis cs` or `compat=1.11`. Then you said "I added `compat=1.11`", then you asked me again how to put the dot in the right place, so I assumed that for some reason that approach didn't work for you.

Comment: @Jake  Yes, I removed "axis cs:" from the `\draw` command, and the dot was plotted correctly.  I was told that the code for making default tick marks is described in chapter 75 of the TikZ manual.  I didn't find it. How do I add a tick mark on the horizontal line, representing the x-axis, that is 3 units to the left of the vertical line, representing the y-axis?

Comment: @Jake  One more "thing."  I will need to label the line and the tick marks.  For the line, you said that I would have to plot the line, the one different from the axes, "using a normal path."  What do you mean by that?  I only care about getting the lines (and tick marks) drawn and labeled.  I don't care which commands I use to get them.

Comment: By "normal path", I meant using `\draw[blue,latex-latex] (-5,-3) -- (5,2) node[above left, pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y = mx + b$};` instead of `\draw[blue,domain=-5:5,samples=2,latex-latex] plot (\x, 0.5*\x - 0.5) node[above left, pos=0.9,font=\footnotesize]{$y = mx + b$};` (so using the `--` syntax instead of `plot`). The `datavisualization` library is described in chapter 75 of TikZ version 3.0. You're probably using 2.1?

Comment: @Jake  I prefer the code for what you call "normal path."  I changed my code.  Thanks.

Comment: @Adelyn, so are now all questions answered in the comments and we can close it or do you need further assistance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.